# Python import firebase module causes program to loop unexpectedly

Tags: python-2.7, firebase

I am using Python2.7 ,Python-firebase 1.2 .

If we comment firebase import then it is giving output only once or else it is giving multiple times.

```
from firebase import firebase

print "result"
```

output:

```
result
result
result
result
```

Answer (score 1):

That `firebase` module was written by *bad programmers* as it performs tasks that you don't explicitly ask for. For that reason, I would advise anybody to steer clear from using that module because you cannot know what other booby traps they might have in their code. Sure, they probably think this behavior is convenient, but convenience is everything but breaking the expectations of programmers (which is the one rule that absolutely every module writer has to follow) and if it was convenient this question wouldn't exist. They do say that it relies heavily on multiprocessing but they don't mention you won't have a say in it:

> The interface heavily depends on the standart multiprocessing library when concurrency comes in. While creating an asynchronous call, an on-demand process pool is created and, the async method is executed by one of the idle process inside the pool. The pool remains alive until the main process dies. So every time you trigger an async call, you always use the same pool. When the method returns, the pool process ships the returning value back to the main process within the callback function provided.

So, all that being said... This happens because the main `__init__.py` of that module imports its `async.py` module, which in turn creates a `multiprocessing.Pool` (set to its `_process_pool`) with 5 fixed slots, and given nothing to work with you get 5 additional processes of your `main` script - hence, it prints out `result` 6 times (the main process and the 5 spawned sub-processes).

Bottom line - do not use this module. There are other alternatives, but if you absolutely have to - guard your code with a main process check:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("result")
```

It will still spawn 5 subprocesses, and wait for all of them to finish (which is rather quick) but at least it won't execute your guarded code.

Comment: I modified value from 5 to 0 in the async.py file . After Execution still it is giving output 6 times. Please help us

Comment: You didn't change the right file because `multiprocessing.Pool` would complain that the minimum number of workers is `1`. The only way to stop it is to use a guard as presented above - yes, it will still spawn unwanted processes but at least it won't execute anything (potentially changing the silly behavior of the module and making it unusable) Either way, don't change the behavior of the module, change the module! Try [`pyfirebase`](https://github.com/afropolymath/pyfirebase) instead, for example

Comment: We Tried Pyfirebase.But if we want to use FirebaseApplication how we can use this from pyfirebase module.

Comment: firebase_2 = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://bluetooth2.firebaseio.com/', None)     it uses firebase..How can we use same FirebaseApplication using pyfirebase..Please help us